# Slim framework tutorial issue - no request parameters passed

Tags: php

[This](http://www.androidhive.info/2014/01/how-to-create-rest-api-for-android-app-using-php-slim-and-mysql-day-12-2/) is the tutorial I followed. I encountered the following error message:

> Required field(s) name, email, password is missing or empty

It looks like I didn't post the correct parameters in my post. But it's not the case. Please refer to my screenshot:

[image]

I debugged the source code and found all the following variables are null:

```
        $name = $app->request->post('name');
        $email = $app->request->post('email');
        $password = $app->request->post('password');
```

Can anybody tell me what could be the reason? Thanks

Comment: Can't help effectively without seeing your form html.

Comment: I don’t know what kind of UI the screenshot is from – but are you sure selecting “application/json” there is the right choice?

Comment: You're right. This should be "application/x-www-form-urlencoded". Thanks.

Comment: check my answer:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/35463607/2995058

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem. At first I used "Poster" for Mozilla Firefox. I got `error: true`. After that I used "Advanced REST client" for Chrome. I got `error: true`. Finally I used `Postman -REST client` and the problem was gone. I got `error: false`. and the successful message.